# how to run hawkbit server as a public server as it is a local server

Tags: swupdate, eclipse-hawkbit, hawkbit

how to run hawkbit server as a public server as it is a local server?

We need a scenario that,

1. Hawkbit server should run on a ubuntu machine, hawkbit url should be public accessible.
2. run script file in on another ubuntu machine server, which uploads the required files to hawkbit server.
3. multiple boards on remote will fetch the swupdate from hawkbit when rollout is started.

how to run hawkbit as a public domain, as remotely device should be able to access the hawkbit for updates?